# Page should show exist instead of blank page

Tags: php

I made login.php file by following video tutorial and I am trying to make so that the page will show **exist** instead of blank page. I know that user exists because I made user with my name on phpMyAdmin.

Her is the code

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (user_exists('Denis') === true) {
echo 'exists';
}
die();

if(empty($_POST) === false) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
}
}
?>
```

Init.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

Comment: please share the code for the function `user_exists` and the contents of `core/init.php` so i can help you better

Comment: your line error_reporting(0); may be hiding an error...

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the `die()` function at line 7

this function terminates the running script

Comment: After it should have echoed 'exists', I suspect something is causing the WSOD before that. But without knowing what core is we have no hope of figuring it out.  The OPmight look in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `user_exists('Denis')` is returning false, since it's getting past the `echo 'exists';` line and hitting the `die()` call.

Comment: It might just not be identical to true.

Comment: What should I do so it will show exist instead of blank page?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are returning your boolean, you might try two "==" signs rather than three. It might not be able to type cast.

Comment: I putted everywhere where there were 3 lines I putted 2 lines and I keep getting blank page.

Comment: As Amdorra said, we need to see user_exists() function to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if (user_exists('Denis')) {
    echo 'exists';
}
```

As long as `user_exists('Denis')` evaluates to true (i.e. is not empty or 0), you will "exists" will be echoed.

If that doesn't work, try to figure out why `user_exists()` is getting a falsy value. There may be something wrong with the logic to check if a user exists.